# Share not working in FB but working in others

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app

Has anyone managed to figure out how to share to Facebook using javascript. I have this code, it works for others but not for facebook

```
tizen.filesystem.resolve("images", function(images) {
var imagePath = images.resolve(imageFileSource);
var appControlData = [new tizen.ApplicationControlData("http://tizen.org/appcontrol/data/path", [imagePath.toURI()])];
var appControl = new tizen.ApplicationControl("http://tizen.org/appcontrol/operation/share", imagePath.toURI(), 
        "image/*", null, appControlData);
tizen.application.launchAppControl(appControl, null,
        function(){
            console.log("launch appControl succeeded");
        }, 
        function(e){
            console.log("No Sharer", "You're phone doesn't seems to have a default image sharer");
        }, 
        null);  });
```

I tried ApplicationControlData("image", [..]) as well removing appControlData. But I cant managed to make it work for facebook only and they wont pass my approve for that!!!

Comment: I have implemented sharing code. but it doesn't show the facebook option. It shows Email, Whatsapp, SMS etc..

Comment: What about you ?

Comment: it shows facebook, i believe the mimetype "image/*" should show it